# How to get and update data from the ngrx store into Observable variable?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, store, ngrx, ngrx-store

I got pretty simple feature module with store/reducers/etc created by @ngrx/schematics. In this feature module i got 2 components - form and items list which is empty by default and u can add items via form. When i add something via form action works, reducer get payload but items list in second component doesn't update.

items list html:

```
<section class="sub-list">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="sub-list--header"><h1>My Subscriptions</h1></header>
    <span *ngIf="length$ | async">Subscriptions count - {{ length$ | async }}</span>
    <main class="sub-list--content" *ngIf="list$ | async as list">
      <div class="sub-list--item" *ngFor="let item of list">
        <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</section>
```

items list component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Store
import * as fromSub from '../../reducers/subscription.reducer';
import * as subActions from '../../actions/subscription.actions';
// Models
import { Subscription } from '../../models/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-list',
  templateUrl: './sub-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-list.component.scss']
})
export class SubListComponent implements OnInit {
  list$: Observable<Subscription[]>;
  length$: Observable<number>;
  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private subStore: Store<fromSub.State>
  ) {
    this.list$ = this.subStore.select('subscriptionsList');
    this.length$ = this.subStore.select('length');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

form component(just in case i did action dispatch wrong):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

// Store
import * as fromSub from '../../reducers/subscription.reducer';
import * as subActions from '../../actions/subscription.actions';
// Models
import { Subscription } from '../../models/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-form',
  templateUrl: './sub-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-form.component.scss']
})
export class SubFormComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  link: string;
  date: Date;
  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private subStore: Store<fromSub.State>
  ) {
    this.price = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addSubscription = (): void => {
    // Snackbar test
    if (!this.name) {
      this.snackBar.open('Name field is empty', 'Close', { duration: 3000 });
      return;
    }
    // if (this.link === '') {}
    if (this.price < 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this.date) {
      this.snackBar.open('Date field is empty', 'Close', { duration: 3000 });
      return;
    }
    const newSub: Subscription = {
      name: this.name,
      price: this.price,
      link: this.link,
      date: this.date,
    };
    this.subStore.dispatch(new subActions.AddSubscription(newSub));
    this.snackBar.open('Subscription added', 'Close', { duration: 3000 });
  }
}
```

module reducer:

```
import { SubscriptionActions, SubscriptionActionTypes } from '../actions/subscription.actions';
import { Subscription } from '../models/Subscription';

export interface State {
  length: number;
  subscriptionsList: Subscription[];
}

export const initialState: State = {
  length: 0,
  subscriptionsList: [],
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: SubscriptionActions): State {
  switch (action.type) {

    case SubscriptionActionTypes.LoadSubscriptions:
      return state;

    case SubscriptionActionTypes.AddSubscription:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        subscriptionsList: state.subscriptionsList.concat(action.payload),
        length: state.subscriptionsList.length + 1
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So it might be the problem in reducer(wrong store update) or in component(wrong select or wrong provider)

Comment: is your hole state  `{ subscriptionsList: Array, lenght: number }`, you don;t have any features in rootStore?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak yes, this app is like simple todo list on which i am learning basics of angular and ngrx. So basically i have a list of items and form to fill this list.

Comment: Ok, please paste part of code where you connecting your reducer with angular module

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak ok so here is my module:
`import * as fromSubscription from './reducers/subscription.reducer';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { SubscriptionEffects } from './effects/subscription.effects';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SubFormComponent, SubListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('subscription', fromSubscription.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([SubscriptionEffects]),
  ],
  exports: [
    SubFormComponent,
    SubListComponent,
  ]`

Answer (score 1):

First thinks first:

Your global store looks like this:

```js
interface RootStore {
  subscription: {
    subscriptionsList: Array<...>,
    length: number;
  }
}
```

So when you want go get `this.lenght$` in component you have to do this:

```
this.lenght$ = this.store.select(rootStore => rootStore.subscription.lenght)
```

When you subscribe to store in component you try to get `length` key on RootStore. It's doesn't exist so you're subscribing to undefined. After dispatch action it's still undefined so you component didn't refresh data.

Comment: i have no root store, for now i have only module store and it directly go to the component

Comment: You made it when you register reducer in store, Check in redux dev tools

Comment: So do i understand correct that all i need is to register my featureModule store into rootStore?

Comment: You already did it: `StoreModule.forFeature('subscription', fromSubscription.reducer)` means you register  `subscription` feature in store with `fromSubscription.reducer`. So only thing to do is select what you want in component but from RootStore, not from `subscription` subState

Comment: doesnt work like this:
    `this.list$ = this.subStore.select(rootStore => rootStore.subscriptionsList);
    this.length$ = this.subStore.select(rootStore => rootStore.length);`
maybe its because my index.ts is empty? and what is store in `this.lenght$ = this.store.select(rootStore => rootStore.subscription.lenght)`?